# How do I install CyanogenMod on Sony Xperia Z1 Compact?

Tags: cyanogenmod, sony-xperia-z1

I have rooted my compact device, but I'm not able to use ROM Manager because the app says my device isn't supported. I am trying to download CyanogenMod on my Z1 Compact. Since ROM Manager doesn't work, how do I install CM?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the official [CyanogenMod wiki for Sony Xperia Z1 Compact](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_amami).